# invalid object name - temp table is out of scope after exec, but I don't know how to fix

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, azure-synapse

Firstly, i do not have any experience with dynamic SQL, this is my first attempt.  i was looking through the answers on here but various attempts to correct this has failed leaving me more confused.

I created a table with looped Months [#Month], and also created a table of transaction codes [#Tran_codes], i need to combine these with transactional data, but am receiving invalid object name '#Trans1'.  i know this is due to the temp table being out of scope but I do not know how to fix it.

This is the code that is giving me issues, please can you help correct or advise where i can read up on the correct syntax to use?

```
   -------------------------------------------------------------------
    PRINT '03. Create a Table with all Tran codes as per "02", with transaction amounts, per month-end date for past 25 months as set out by "01" '
    -------------------------------------------------------------------


    DECLARE 
         @i              INT
        ,@j              INT
        ,@Monthend_Date  varchar(50)
        ,@Month_String   VARCHAR(6)
        ,@SQL            VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @i = 1
    SET @j = (SELECT MAX(RowNum) FROM #Month)

    WHILE @i <= @j
    BEGIN

        SET @Month_String   = (SELECT MonthString FROM #Month WHERE RowNum = @i)     

    IF @i = 1
    BEGIN

    ----------------------------------------------------------
    SET @SQL = '
            IF OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..#Trans1'') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Trans
              CREATE TABLE #Trans1
              WITH
              (
               DISTRIBUTION = HASH(Tran_Date_Key)
               ,LOCATION = USER_DB
              )
               AS   
               SELECT
            Monthend_Date = ''' + CONVERT(Varchar(30), @Monthend_Date) + '''
            ,Trans.Tran_Code_Key
            ,TD.Tran_Code
            ,TD.Description
            ,Amount
               FROM DATASTORE_MIS.[dbo].vwF_Transaction_'+ @Month_String +' Trans
            inner join DATASTORE_MIS.[dbo].vwF_Transaction_Description_'+ @Month_String +' as TD on Trans.Journal_No = TD.Journal_No
                                                                                    AND Trans.[Tran_Date_Key] = TD.[Tran_Date_Key]
               '

    EXEC (@SQL)

End
ELSE
BEGIN

    SET @SQL = '

        INSERT INTO #Trans1
        SELECT
        Monthend_Date = ''' + CONVERT(Varchar(30), @Monthend_Date) + '''
        ,Trans.Tran_Code_Key
        ,TD.Tran_Code
        ,TD.Description
        ,Amount
        FROM DATASTORE_MIS.[dbo].vwF_Transaction_'+ @Month_String +' Trans
        inner join DATASTORE_MIS.[dbo].vwF_Transaction_Description_'+ @Month_String +' as TD on Trans.Journal_No = TD.Journal_No
                                                                                    AND Trans.[Tran_Date_Key] = TD.[Tran_Date_Key]
               '
    EXEC (@SQL)
END

SET @i = @i + 1

END
```

Comment: Create the temp table with the needed schema before executing the dynamic SQL and load using `INSERT...SELECT` in the dynamic SQL statement. The table will then be available in both the outer scope and inner scope (dynamic SQL statements).

Comment: Added the `azure-sql-data-warehouse` tag to your question based on the syntax you are using.